# How do I check If not condition in Dust.js templates

Tags: dust.js

How do I check for if not condition in the Dust.js templates?

```
{?tags}
{:else}
  <p>Sorry, There are no tags!</p>
{/tags}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is built into Dust, using the `^` tag (often called the "not" tag):

```
{^tags}
  <p>Sorry, There are no tags!</p>
{/tags}
```